# Sending Entity Object in Response which contains blob

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, blob, httpresponse

I am trying to create a springboot usermanagement application.

I have an entity object which contains two blob elements.Here is my entity object.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="user_meta_profile")
    public class UserMetaProfile implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;

    @Column(name = "resume_file")
    @Lob
    private Blob resume_file;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    @Lob
    private Blob photo;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public Blob getResume_file() {
        return resume_file;
    }

    public void setResume_file(Blob resume_file) {
        this.resume_file = resume_file;
    }

    public Blob getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(Blob photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

As you can see there are two blob items 'resume_file' and 'photo'.

I want to send back a JSON response to the API call.

My Controller code is as shown below.

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/v1")
    public class UsersController {

    @Autowired 
        private IUserMetaProfileService userMetaProfileService;


    @GetMapping("MetaProfile/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<UserMetaProfile> getUserMetaProfileById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
            UserMetaProfile userMetaProfile = userMetaProfileService.getUsersById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<UserMetaProfile>(userMetaProfile, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
```

But when I call the API, I get the exception:

```
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",

 "message": "Could not write JSON document: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
...

   ...nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Comment: You try to add a binary file to a JSON-String. This is not possible. If you really want to add binary files to a JSON-String, you have to base64 encode the binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON cannot contain binary data you need to serialize those fields as something else. You have a couple of options:

1. If you intend to show the binary as an image (since yours is a photo) you can serialize it as a data uri.
2. Send links to photos instead and create a controller method that will output the binary data with the appropriate content type (beyond the scope here).

So for Option 1 you can do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_meta_profile")
public class UserMetaProfile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;

    @Column(name = "resume_file")
    @Lob
    private Blob resume_file;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    @Lob
    private Blob photo;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore // disable serializing this field by default
    public Blob getResume_file() {
        return resume_file;
    }

    // serialize as data uri insted
    @JsonProperty("resumeData")
    public String getResume() {
      // just assuming it is a word document. you would need to cater for different media types
      return "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64," + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(resume_file.getBytes()));
    }

    public void setResume_file(Blob resume_file) {
        this.resume_file = resume_file;
    }

    @JsonIgnore // disable this one too
    public Blob getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    // serialize as data uri instead
    @JsonProperty("photoData")
    public String getPhotoBase64() {
      // just assuming it is a jpeg. you would need to cater for different media types
      return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(photo.getBytes()));
    }

    public void setPhoto(Blob photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

For the photo bit the value of the `photoData` JSON attribute can be set directly as the `src` attribute of an `img` tag and the photo will be rendered in the HTML. With the resume file you can attach it as an href to a `<a>` tag with a `download` attribute so it can be downloaded:

```
<a href={photoData value here} download>Download Resume File</a>
```

Just as an FYI if the files are large the JSON will be huge and it might also slow down the browser.